# Migration JOnAS to JBoss : carol.properties

Tags: java, spring, jboss, rmi, jonas

I am currently trying to perform the migration of a web application from **JOnAS 5.2.2** to **JBoss 7.2.0**.

I am getting some troubles with the deployment under the JBoss server because my application is usually using the CAROL library provided with JOnAS.

Usually, the `carol.properties` file is under **JONAS_HOME/conf/**.

My application is using it through this bean :

```
  <bean id="clientConnector"
    class="com.szk.myapp.common.jonas.JonasMBeanServerConnectionFactoryBean">
    <property name="jrmpUrl" value="$kpi{rmi.host}" />
    <property name="jonasInstanceName" value="${jonas.server.name}" />
  </bean>
```

But with JBoss, it does not work : of course, it is looking for the **carol.properties** file under the path **null/conf/**

```
# Copyright (C) 2002-2007 ObjectWeb
#
# CAROL: Common Architecture for RMI ObjectWeb Layer
#
# This library is developed inside the ObjectWeb Consortium,
# http://www.ow2.org
#
# This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
# modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
# License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
# version 2.1 of the License, or any later version.
#
# This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
# Lesser General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
# License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
# Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307
# USA
#
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------
# $Id: carol.properties 19269 2010-02-21 14:17:59Z manmand $
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------

# jonas rmi activation (iiop, irmi, jrmp, lmi)
carol.protocols=jrmp

# RMI IRMI URL
carol.irmi.url=rmi://localhost:1098

# RMI JRMP URL
carol.jrmp.url=rmi://localhost:1099

# RMI IIOP URL
carol.iiop.url=iiop://localhost:2001

# RMI LMI URL (no listening port)
carol.lmi.url=rmi://localhost:0


######################################################################
#             Advanced Configuration for IRMI
######################################################################
# Exported objects will listen on this port for remote method
# invocations.
#A value of 0 will cause a random port to be selected.
# This is the default value.
# Warning : if the port is set (not 0) with the value 'n', be aware that
# the port 'n + 1' will be used by the JMX server.
# So, for the firewall configuration, you have to open the port numbers 'n'
# and 'n+1'.
carol.irmi.server.port=0

# Use only a single interface when creating the registry
# (specified in carol.irmi.url property)
# Use all interfaces available [default configuration = false]
carol.irmi.interfaces.bind.single=false

######################################################################
#             Advanced Configuration for JRMP
######################################################################
# If true, local call with jrmp are optimized. If you get "ClassCastException
# with 2 beans in different jars, you should set it at "false".
carol.jvm.rmi.local.call=false

# If true a local Naming context is used (to be used only with a collocated registry)
carol.jvm.rmi.local.registry=true

# The value of this port is used to set the port of the objects listener.
# This allow to use this port for a firewall configuration.
# If registry and server are on same host, the two ports to open are the following and the registry port.
# 0 means random port [default configuration = 0]
carol.jrmp.server.port=0

# Use only a single interface when creating the registry
# (specified in carol.jrmp.url property)
# Use all interfaces available [default configuration = false]
carol.jrmp.interfaces.bind.single=false


######################################################################
#             Advanced Configuration for IIOP
######################################################################
# The value of this port is used to set the port of the objects listener.
# This allow to use this port for a firewall configuration.
# If registry and server are on same host, the two ports to open are the following and the registry port.
# 0 means random port [default configuration = 0]
carol.iiop.server.port=0

# The value of this port is used to set the SSL port of the objects listener.
# Note that this port musn't not be set to 0 as it is used for CsiV2.
# but this port is used only if SSL mode is enable.
# So by default, there is no listener on this port
# [default configuration = not used]
carol.iiop.server.sslport=2003

# Delegate used by JOnAS for rmi-iiop protocol
carol.iiop.PortableRemoteObjectClass=org.ow2.jonas.registry.carol.delegate.JacORBPRODelegate

######################################################################
#             Advanced JNDI Configuration
######################################################################
carol.jndi.java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.ow2.jonas.lib.naming
```

Does anyone have any idea about how to make it work under JBoss ?

Any suggestion is very welcomed.

Thank you.